# Why does journald still log to the active console?

Tags: terminal, logfiles

I'm using Manjaro ARM (64bit), and by default it seems to log always to the active console. It took me a while to figure out how to change the `cmdline` to using `console=/dev/tty1` instead of `console=/dev/tt0` (there's no `/boot/cmdline.txt` since it's using U-BOOT, I had to modify `/boot/boot.txt` instead). But neither that nor changing `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`'s `TTYPath=/dev/tty1` or `MaxLevelConsole=err` seems to change the behaviour. What other settings could be causing this? The output is e.g.

```
[36300.723412] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Timeout waiting for grafx power OK
```

Which I also can obtain from `dmesg --follow`. (That error itself also suggests something fishy but unrelated to my question)

Comment: Slightly more general question on unix.se: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/526200/863, but maybe there's truly something specific to RPi or at least ARM...